# iCarousel's index

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to determine the index of carousel?. Or the array's index loaded in it?. I have loaded my image from the NSDocumentDirectory.

```
self.myImages = [NSMutableArray new];  
for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) 
{ 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]]; 
       if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 
            NSLog(@"file exists");
        } 

}
```

and added them in the iCarousel view:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[myImages objectAtIndex:index]];
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your question, you can try to use `tag` property of UIView for the comparison. For example:

In `viewForItemAtIndex:`

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index  reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[myImages objectAtIndex:index]];
    view.tag = index;
    return view;
}
```

Compare `currentItemView` to another image

```
If (int == [(UIImageView*)[self.carousel currentItemView] tag]) { 
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where (in code) do you need the carousel's index ? You know it when you add the images to the carousel (in `viewForItemAtIndex:`) and, also, when you tap the carousel (in `didSelectItemAtIndex:`).

Also, you could use the carousel's `currentItemIndex` property.

Comment: Im trying to compare it to another image, so I'm taking of assigning a value or something to the array. For example: `if(int == carousel index/integer/value where it stop) { //do something} ....`